# 301 redirect if filename end has different characters

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

The filenames that I want to redirect are like following:

```
/wp-content/uploads/2022/06/DIDUFKU-BLINGSY9-bbteew-hhh-2022-3-110.pdf
/wp-content/uploads/2022/06/DIDUFKU-BLINGSY9-bbteew-hhh-2022-1-510.pdf
/wp-content/uploads/2022/06/DIDUFKU-BLINGSY9-bbteew-hhh-2022-2-116.pdf
```

etc.

I want to 301 redirect all that contains the unchanged URL part `/wp-content/uploads/2022/06/DIDUFKU-BLINGSY9-bbteew-hhh-2022-` to a file: `/wp-content/uploads/2022/06/DIDUFKU-BLINGSY9-bbteew-hhh-2022a.pdf`

I tried this in htaccess without any success:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+/)DIDUFKU-BLINGSY9-bbteew-hhh-2022-(.*) /wp-content/uploads/2022/06/DIDUFKU-BLINGSY9-bbteew-hhh-2022a.pdf [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Where are you putting this rule? That rule should redirect as you require (although it could be improved), but it depends where you've put it. The order of directives in the `.htaccess` file is important. Do the URLs you are redirecting _from_ still exist as physical files?

Comment: Those files are deleted, those were duplicate files I decided to redirect but not redirecting. I put that rule in htaccess file in WP directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Those files are deleted, those were duplicate files I decided to redirect but not redirecting. I put that rule in htaccess file in WP directory

If those files are deleted and you put this rule at the end of the `.htaccess` file, *after* the WordPress code block then it won't do anything since the request will be routed through WordPress and mostly likely trigger a (WordPress generated) 404 Not Found response.

This rule needs to go near the top of the `.htaccess` file, *before* the WordPress code block. ie. Before the `# BEGIN WordPress` comment marker.

However, your rule can be improved (to avoid unnecessary repetition), for example:

```
RewriteRule ^(wp-content/uploads/2022/06/DIDUFKU-BLINGSY9-bbteew-hhh-2022)-[\d-]+\.pdf$ /$1a.pdf
```

The `$1` backreference contains the captured group from the `RewriteRule` *pattern*, ie. the string `wp-content/uploads/2022/06/DIDUFKU-BLINGSY9-bbteew-hhh-2022`.

You should test first with a 302 (temporary) redirect to avoid potential caching issues.

Comment: Thank you! It worked when I put it above the # BEGIN WordPress